# Effectively reading a large, active Python log file

Tags: python, windows, logging, text-files

When my Python script is writing a large amount of logs to a text file line by line using the Python built-in logging library, in my Delphi-powered Windows program I want to **effectively** read all newly added logs (lines).

1. When the Python scripting is logging
   to the file, my Windows program will
   keep a **readonly** file handle to
   that log file;
2. I'll use the Windows API to get
   informed when the log file is
   changed; Once the file is changed, it'll read the newly appended lines.

I'm new to Python, do you see any possible problem with this approach? Does the Python logging lib lock the entire log? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *ʇsәɹoɈ* commented, the standard FileHandler logger does not lock the file, so it should work. However, if for some reason you cannot keep you lock on the file - then I'd recommend having your other app open the file periodically, record the position it's read to and then seek back to that point later. I know the Linux *DenyHosts* program uses this approach when dealing with log files that it has to monitor for a long period of time. In those situations, simply holding a lock isn't feasible, since directories may move, the file get rotated out, etc. Though it does complicate things in that then you have to store filename + read position in persistent state somewhere.

Comment: Since in the EXE program it has to show the newly added log entries in real time, I'm afraid closing and re-opening the log file will cause performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the logging handler you use, of course, but as you can see from the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/logging/__init__.py), logging.FileHandler does not currently create any file locks.  By default, it opens files in 'a' (append) mode, so as long as your Windows calls can handle that, you should be fine.